# Retrieve AWS cloudwatch logs using Laravel

Tags: laravel, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I enabled cloudwatch log for a feature and now I want to observe the logs programmatically and maybe perform other operations.

For that, I need to retrieve the data from cloudwatch. As far as possible, I would like to avoid exporting my data to S3 bucket. Is there any other way to retrieve logs from cloudwatch? maybe Api call?

I did come across 'Call GetLogEvents or FilterLogEvents' but it doesn't exactly clarify how I can retrieve the data.

There also seems to be quite a few libraries that handle logging data TO cloudwatch FROM Laravel, are there any libraries that does the exact opposite?

EDIT

I came across a method GetLogEvents() for the cloudwatch events and I implemented it like:

```
$client = AWS::createClient('cloudwatchlogs');
$result = $client->GetLogEvents([
        'logGroupName' => '*****',
        'logStreamName' => '06****-****-****-****-...',
    ]);
return $result;
```

It gives me the defition of this particular log event but not any data within. I specifically need the data within the event logs. Is there any method to extract the data?

Comment: have you tried to implement cloudwatch in your laravel application with aws php sdk.

Comment: No, but let me try, I'll update if anything goes wrong.